# How to use User Control in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a vb.net (windows) project download from internet. It is in vb.net  and it has user controls.
This project contains a single form alone and this form uses user control.
But the error is
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Use the "new" keyword to create object instance.

Comment: You must be using on object before you have instantiated it. Can you show your code where the error is being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the code is adding a control dynamically...

```
Dim myControl as myUserControl
myControl.name = "control1"
'+ any other properties set
myForm.Controls.Add(myControl)
```

This will give the error you have seen...

```
Dim myControl as New myUserControl
myControl.name = "control1"
'+ any other properties set
myForm.Controls.Add(myControl)
```

Would be the fix - This is how you can add may instances of the same control... just make sure they have unique names.